# PHP - Sharing session partially working

Tags: php, session, websocket

When I logged in into my website, there are 3 items set into the session like this

```
$_SESSION['language'] = 'US';
$_SESSION['account'] = array();
$_SESSION['account']['id']  = 1;
$_SESSION['account']['session'] = session_id()
```

Then, when I go to the admin panel and do a var_dump() of $_SESSION all the 3 items in te session is shown. So far so good.

But when I connect to my own created websocket server it reads the $_SESSION['language'] but it can't read the

> $_SESSION['account']

So this is what I am doing: Send the cookie (PHPSESSID) in the header when connecting to the websocket stream. Then just before handshaking I used the following code which is only var_dumping the "language" and NOT the "account"

```
if (preg_match("/PHPSESSID=(.*?)(?:;|\r\n)/", $data, $match))   
{
    session_id($matches[1]);
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    session_write_close();
}
```

So to make a short story: It reads the $_SESSION['language'] but it doesn't find the $_SESSION['account'] before handshaking. Does anybody know more about this? (And i am sure the sessions are started and they aren't destroy somewhere)

Comment: try to echo $_SESSION['account'][0];

Comment: and you dont need this $_SESSION['account'] = array();, you can directly use $_SESSION['account']['id']

Comment: `preg_match` has `$match` but you are using `$matches`.

Comment: Can you try removing this line `$_SESSION['account'] = array();`?

Comment: Sometimes I can be really stupid, just like now. Indeed after fixing the good variables used in preg_match like @gre_gor noticed and after removing the array() like ali-gajani and mohade said it is working now. Thank you so much guys, really helpfull and also thanks for thr quick reply's!